# Should it be possible to earn the yearling badge without visiting the site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, yearling-badge

A user earns the yearling badge for being

> active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation.

But I found a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774578/partick-hose) who asked a great question some years ago and he is still getting reputation for it. He was last seen on the site on Feb 11 '12 at 12:36, however he earned [the yearling badge again on may 28 at 19:00](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=774578).

I understand that the most users don't earn so much reputation without being active on the site, but could we add a requirement to have been seen in the last year?

Comment: Meh, who cares. He may be a yearling, but he ain't no [fanatic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic).

Comment: "Active member for a year" - there should be at least _something_ on your activity list to count as active. Otherwise we're just giving a badge for having registered. Badges should surely be there to reward something good. Completely failing to be active doesn't deserve even a bronze badge, let alone a silver one.

Comment: If a badge is awarded to someone that never signs on, is that person motivated?